# Imported PowerPoint images are several times larger than my slides

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

Whenever I import a high-resolution photograph into PowerPoint by dragging-and dropping it, the default photo size ends up being several times larger than my slide.

[image: A very large imported image]

Having to manually resize imported images to fit on a single slide every time is a bit cumbersome.

Strangely, this issue doesn't seem to affect all images equally. There are certain high-resolution images which are consistently scaled to a reasonable size without any issues.

**How can I limit the maximum size of imported images so they fit on my PowerPoint slides?**

Comment: What happens to images can depend on several factors, including the PPT version, whether the image file type supports suggested DPI values as part of the file format definition and, if so, the size/dpi of the file.  The fact that you're drag/dropping the file can have an effect also; it's better practice to user PPT's Insert | Picture command instead.